# GTX 1070 (DP 1.4, HDMI 2.0) => G-Sync (VRR) => LG OLEDC9 (HDMI 2.1)

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, tv, displayport, g-sync

I am trying to get **G-Sync** @ 4K60Hz with my setup:

Graphics: [GTX 1070](https://de.msi.com/Graphics-Card/GeForce-GTX-1070-AERO-8G-OC/Specification) with HDMI 2.0 and DP 1.4

Display: [LG OLEDC9](https://www.lg.com/tv/lg-OLED65C97LA) with HDMI 2.1

I already did some research and it turns out you can't get G-Sync via HDMI from that graphics card, only via Display Port. However, my TV does not have a Display Port input, so I am wondering if it will be possible to buy a DP 1.4 => HDMI 2.1 cable and then have G-Sync enabled? I can't find a definitive answer to that. Maybe someone here knows.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I *think* that the electronics essentially "falls back" to the other type of connection when you use passive converters. As a result if your graphics card only supports HDMI 2.0 without G-Sync then the DP will fall back to HDMI without G-Sync. An active DP to HDMI converter might work, but you'd have to find one that specifically knows how to convert whatever methods DP uses to indicate compatibility to the same style used by HDMI. I do not know whether such a thing is simple to achieve but different specifications typically handle things subtly differently enough to be annoying.

Comment: That is not a definitive answer, but a very reasonable one. Thanks.